# how can i robustly detect a relative path in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Maybe i am making it to hard (and i should just look for a prefix of `./` and `../`) but I don't want to re-invent the wheel and write a function to correctly detect relative paths (for all platforms, etc.)

### Existing library?

Are there `npm` packages that do this? Surely this problem has been solved...

### Approaches?

Barring an existing library, my intended approach was to use the `path` module functions to `join` the possibly relative path to a known prefix, and then see what the result was, with the assumption that `path.join('some_base', possiblyRelative)` would allow some sort of distinguishing characteristic in a platform safe way.

Any other suggestions? Approaches?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a little late but for others searching on the same issue:

since node version 0.12.0 you have the the [`path.isAbsolute(path)`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_isabsolute_path)  function from the `path` module. To detect if your path is relative use the negation of it:

i.e:

```
var path = require('path');
if( ! path.isAbsolute(myPath)) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 10):

UPDATE2: TomDotTom found a more robust answer here: [How to check if a path is absolute or relative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21698906/how-to-check-if-a-path-is-absolute-or-relative/30714706#30714706)

Reproduced here (but in the inverse):

```
var path = require('path');
function isRelative(p) {
  return path.normalize(p + '/') !== path.normalize(path.resolve(p) + '/');
}
```

For node v0.12 and above, I recommend `path.isAbsolute` instead.

Comment: isRelative('/foo/bar/)
>> false

Comment: @TomDotTom '/foo/bar' is not a relative path in linux. Care to explain more why you think that's an incorrect result?

Comment: @B_T the isRelative function above will return false for '/foo/bar' indicating it's not a relative path.

Comment: @TomDotTom '/foo/bar' *isn't* a relative path.. 'foo/bar' is.

Comment: @B_T I suggest you open up node and try out the code: isRelative('/foo/bar') >> false; isRelative('foo/bar') >> true

Comment: YES TOM, THAT IS THE CORRECT BEHAVIOR

Comment: @B_T apologies I wasn't paying attention and seem to have accidentally been trolling you :-/. But I still think there is an issue, if you could run these four examples and comment on the one marked (in my opinion) inccorect:   
[OK] isRelative('foo/bar') >> true;    
[OK isRelative('foo/bar/') >> true;    
[OK] isRelative('/foo/bar') >> false;    
[INCORRECT] isRelative('/foo/bar/') >> true

Comment: Ah, ok you do have a point there. Looks like `resolve` adds a trailing '/' and `normalize` doesn't. Thanks for persisting in telling me what's wrong! I think I can fix this by removing the trailing slash from the output of `resolve`

Comment: @TomDotTom Ugh, fixing this issue is harder than it looks

Comment: @B_T shameless plug http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21698906/how-to-check-if-a-path-is-absolute-or-relative/30714706#30714706

Comment: Hope you don't mind me using your answer to fix mine

Answer (score 0):

```
function isRelative(str)
{
    //Remove quotes as it can potentially mess up the string
    str=str.replace("\'\"",'');
    return str.substring(0,2)=="./"||str.substring(0,3)=="../"; 
}
```

In this example we only allow relative strings for the beginning of the string path