# How to check if a path is absolute or relative

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, directory, absolute

UNIX absolute path starts with '/', whereas Windows starts with alphabet 'C:' or '\'. Does node.js has a standard multiplatform function to check if a path is absolute or relative ?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Since node version 0.12.0 you can use the [`path.isAbsolute(path)`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_isabsolute_path)  function from the [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) module.

i.e:

```
var path = require('path');
if(path.isAbsolute(myPath)) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: note that isAbsolute seems to return true for any path that starts with /, whether on Windows or Mac (not sure about *nix)

Comment: As Alexander Mills pointed out, this answer is wrong. If your relative path starts with a `/` (as all relative paths usually do) then this method will return true, which is wrong. I don't know why it was selected as the correct answer, this is dangerous and makes SO unreliable.

Comment: @SproutCoder This answer is correct. Maybe you're thinking of relative paths in the sense of http URLs? The Node.js utility `path.isAbsolute` is meant to be used for filesystem paths where an "absolute path" by definition starts with a slash. See http://www.linfo.org/path.html, for example.

Comment: Be aware that `isAbsolute`, when handed paths beginning with `~` on unix or unix-like systems, will return `false`. While those paths are indeed relative to the current user's user directory, they are not relative to the *current* directory, so changing directories doesn't affect what they resolve to. In this sense, those paths are absolute, which could be surprising to some people.

Answer (score 12):

You could use

```
path.resolve(yourPath)===yourPath
```

If your path isn't normalized, use

```
path.resolve( yourPath ) == path.normalize( yourPath )
```

Comment: There's also a isAbsolute function in the source even if I don't find it in docs and it doesn't seem to be available : https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/path.js#L206

Comment: Yep, I don't know why there isn't in the doc but for now I think that I will use your response, for security.

Comment: The function is in fact in unstable (0.11) but not in the last stable.

Comment: This doesn't work if `yourPath` isn't already normalized (eg: it doesn't work with `///a//..//b//`. The corrent solution is: `path.resolve( yourPath ) == path.normalize( yourPath )`

Comment: This answer is a bit ambiguous. What does this check prove?

Comment: I believe the following is more robust:  

    function isAbsolute(p) {
        return path.normalize(p + '/') === path.normalize(path.resolve(p) + '/');
    }

Comment: The function `isAbsolute` mentioned in previous comments is now in the docs: [Node.js v18 path.isAbsolute method](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/path.html#pathisabsolutepath)

Answer (score 10):

As commented to dystroy's answer, the proposed solutions don't work if an absolute path is not already normalized (for example the path: `///a//..//b//./`).

A correct solution is:

```
path.resolve(yourPath) === path.normalize(yourPath)
```

---

As [Marc Diethelm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546491/marc-diethelm) suggests in the comments, this has still some issues, since `path.resolve` removes trailing slashes while `path.normalize` doesn't.

I'm not sure how these function exactly behave (as you can read in the comments), anyway the following snippet seem to work fine at least in Linux environments:

```
path.resolve(yourPath) === path.normalize(yourPath).replace( RegExp(path.sep+'$'), '' );
```

Comment: However since `normalize` preserves trailing slashes your solution needs to be enhanced. `path.resolve(_yourPath) === path.normalize(_yourPath).replace(/[\/|\\]$/, '')`, will work reliably.

Comment: @MarcDiethelm: you're very right, I never noticed. I'll try to fix the answer taking into account your suggestion! Anyway your solution still doesn't work perfectly, for example it fails with `'/\\'`. Is there any specific reason to remove trailing backslashes? Is it to support windows paths or what else?

Comment: exactly checking for a trailing backslash is need on Windows. re: it fails with '/\\'. I don't understand, can you elobarate? Is that supposed to be a path you test for?!

Comment: @MarcDiethelm: yes, exactly. I'm running Node on a Linux machine. If I pass to your function the `'/\\'` string, `path.resolve('/\\')` returns `'/\\'`, while `path.normalize('/\\').replace(/[\/|\\]$/, '')` returns `'/'`. The line I added to this response seems to work fine for me on Linux, but might be other issues (maybe on Windows?)

Comment: The path `'/\\'` seems like a real edge case for me. Maybe try unescaping first? I'm not a fan of invoking the RegExp constructor with all its overhead here. `path.sep` looks nice at first. But basically we just want to remove ANY (Windows or else) trailing slashes before comparing. Here's my amended version that works for a root `'/'` path too: `path.resolve(yourPath) === path.normalize(yourPath).replace(/(.+)([\/|\\])$/, '$1')`.

Comment: This does not work with node v0.10.35 on Windows. If you have an absolute path without drive letter, this will fail because `path.normalize()` does not prepend drive letter.

Answer (score 3):

This is a little convoluted, but the most robust way I've found using just the (pre node 0.12.0) path module

```
function isAbsolute(p) {
    return path.normalize(p + '/') === path.normalize(path.resolve(p) + '/');
}
```

It should be noted that path.isAbsolute exists from node 0.12.0 onwards.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea about node.js, but you can see the source of path.js in github:
https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/path.js

You can see:

```
// windows version
exports.isAbsolute = function(path) {
    var result = splitDeviceRe.exec(path),
    device = result[1] || '',
    isUnc = device && device.charAt(1) !== ':';
    // UNC paths are always absolute
    return !!result[2] || isUnc;
};
```

And:

```
// posix version
exports.isAbsolute = function(path) {
    return path.charAt(0) === '/';
};
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    isRelative(url){
        return (/^(\.){1,2}(\/){1,2}$/.test(url.slice(0,3)) ||
        /(\/){1,2}(\.){1,2}(\/){1,2}/.test(url)); 
    }
```

This makes it easy to check whether a path is relative despite of absence of node path module API.

```
(/^(\.|~){1,2}(\/){1,2}$/.test(url.slice(0,3))
```

this part checks if the path string starts with the "./" or "../" or "~/". 
If it does, Boolean true is returned. Otherwise the next test is executed.

```
/(\/){1,2}(\.){1,2}(\/){1,2}/.test(url)
```

This just checks if the path string has either "/./" or "/../". and returns  true on any and false on neither.

If any of the two tests is true then the path string is relative.

For windows.

```
    isRelative(url){
        return (/^(\.){1,2}(\\){1,2}$/.test(url.slice(0,3)) ||
        /(\\){1,2}(\.){1,2}(\\){1,2}/.test(url)); 
    }
```

Comment: Please Explain what you did.

Comment: How can you define paths starting with `~` as relative? They may be relative, but not to the current directory. It seems like there are really three states and `isAbsolute` is a bad function because it misleads. Paths starting with `~` are stable and don't change depending on the current directory; in this sense they are absolute...